# i hava two spinner in my application how to reload the selected spinner items

Tags: android, android-spinner

repeate selected spinner items like first i selcted A and B it  displays AB second time selct BA i want to display AB and BA one below another

```
sp_spinner_a=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_spinner_a);
        sp_spinner_b=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_spinner_b);

        lay2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay2);
        lay5=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay5);
        sp_spinner_a.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        sp_spinner_b.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
          // Spinner Drop down elements
        String[] AgeArr = {"SELECT", "A", "B"};
         String[] iiemsArr = {"SELECT", "a", "b"};


          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AgeArr);

          // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
          dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

          // attaching data adapter to spinner
          sp_spinner_a.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, iiemsArr);

          // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
          dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

          // attaching data adapter to spinner
          sp_spinner_b.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String isChecking=(String) sp_spinner_a.getSelectedItem();
    String isCheckingb=(String) sp_spinner_b.getSelectedItem();

    if(isChecking.equals("SELECT")){
        lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lay5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }else{
        lay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, I am unable to get what you mean by displaying AB or BA, which are actually drop down elements of your spinner and only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: From First Spinner I am selected A and from Second Spinner i am Selected B DISPLAY Both the Sinner items like AB

Comment: and then second time i am selected B from first spinner and i am selected A from second spinner it will display BA whem i select second time it display BA but i want display BA along with first time selcted items(AB)